# WSO2 Identity Server error starting, cannot find admin

Tags: ldap, wso2, wso2-identity-server

Starting WSO2 Identity Server for the first time gives me this error:

> "Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Admin user
>   can not be created in primary user store. User store is read only.
>   Please pick a user name which is exist in the primary user store as
>   Admin user"

```
<UserManager>
<Realm>
    <Configuration>
        <AddAdmin>false</AddAdmin>
        <AdminRole>admins</AdminRole>
        <AdminUser>
            <UserName>cn=Directory Manager</UserName>
            <Password>xxxxxxxx</Password>
        </AdminUser>
        <EveryOneRoleName>everyone</EveryOneRoleName> <!-- By default users in this role sees the registry root -->
        <Property name="dataSource">jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</Property>
    </Configuration>


    <UserStoreManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager">
        <Property name="TenantManager">org.wso2.carbon.user.core.tenant.CommonHybridLDAPTenantManager</Property>
        <Property name="ConnectionURL">ldap://localhost:389</Property>
        <Property name="ConnectionName">cn=Directory Manager</Property>
        <Property name="ReadOnly">true</Property>
        <Property name="ConnectionPassword">oursecretpassword</Property>
        <Property name="passwordHashMethod">PLAIN_TEXT</Property>
        <Property name="UserNameListFilter">(objectClass=person)</Property>
        <Property name="UserEntryObjectClass">pccperson</Property>
        <Property name="UserSearchBase">ou=People,dc=pcc.edu,dc=cp</Property>
        <Property name="UserNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=person)(uid=?))</Property>
        <Property name="UserNameAttribute">uid</Property>
        <Property name="PasswordJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
        <Property name="UsernameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>
        <Property name="UsernameJavaRegEx">[a-zA-Z0-9._-|//]{3,30}$</Property>
        <Property name="RolenameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>
        <Property name="RolenameJavaRegEx">[a-zA-Z0-9._-|//]{3,30}$</Property>
        <Property name="ReadGroups">true</Property>
        <Property name="WriteGroups">false</Property>
        <Property name="EmptyRolesAllowed">true</Property>
        <Property name="GroupSearchBase">ou=Groups,dc=pcc,dc=edu</Property>
        <Property name="GroupNameListFilter">(objectClass=groupofuniquenames)</Property>
        <Property name="GroupEntryObjectClass">groupofuniquenames</Property>
        <Property name="GroupNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=groupofuniquenames)(cn=?))</Property>
        <Property name="GroupNameAttribute">cn</Property>
        <Property name="MembershipAttribute">uniqueMember</Property>
        <Property name="UserRolesCacheEnabled">true</Property>
        <Property name="MaxRoleNameListLength">100</Property>
        <Property name="MaxUserNameListLength">100</Property>
        <Property name="SCIMEnabled">false</Property>
    </UserStoreManager>
```

> TID: [0] [IS] [2015-05-22 11:35:10,888]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService} -  Database already exists. Not creating a new database. {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService}
>   TID: [0] [IS] [2015-05-22 11:35:11,233]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  LDAP connection created successfully in read-only mode {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager}
>   TID: [0] [IS] [2015-05-22 11:35:11,841] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm} -  Cannot create org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm}
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:329)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.initializeObjects(DefaultRealm.java:195)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:104)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:223)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.(DefaultRealmService.java:101)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.(DefaultRealmService.java:114)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:69)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
>   Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Admin user can not be created in primary user store. User store is read only. Please pick a user name which is exist in the primary user store as Admin user
>           at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.addInitialAdminData(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:3206)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.(ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.java:166)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.(ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.java:97)
>           ... 27 more
>   TID: [0] [IS] [2015-05-22 11:35:11,844] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService} -  Cannot initialize the realm. {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService}
>   org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:370)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.initializeObjects(DefaultRealm.java:195)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:104)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:223)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.(DefaultRealmService.java:101)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.(DefaultRealmService.java:114)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:69)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
>   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:329)
>           ... 22 more
>   Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Admin user can not be created in primary user store. User store is read only. Please pick a user name which is exist in the primary user store as Admin user
>           at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.addInitialAdminData(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:3206)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.(ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.java:166)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.(ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.java:97)
>           ... 27 more
>   TID: [0] [IS] [2015-05-22 11:35:11,845] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator} -  Cannot start User Manager Core bundle {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator}
>   org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Cannot initialize the realm.
>           at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:231)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.(DefaultRealmService.java:101)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.(DefaultRealmService.java:114)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:69)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
>   Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:370)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.initializeObjects(DefaultRealm.java:195)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:104)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:223)
>           ... 19 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:329)
>           ... 22 more
>   Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Admin user can not be created in primary user store. User store is read only. Please pick a user name which is exist in the primary user store as Admin user
>           at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.addInitialAdminData(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:3206)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.(ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.java:166)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.(ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.java:97)
>           ... 27 more

I've tried setting AdminRole to `'admins' and 'cn=admins'`.  Same error either way.

I don't have a ton of experience setting up LDAP servers from scratch, but I think I installed 389-DS correctly.

See my group entry:

> ldapsearch -b "cn=Admins,ou=Groups,dc=pcc,dc=edu" -D "cn=Directory
>   Manager" -W  cn=* Enter LDAP Password:
>
> dn: cn=admins,ou=Groups,dc=pcc,dc=edu objectClass: top objectClass:
>   groupofuniquenames uniqueMember: uid=jwhitene,ou=People,dc=pcc,dc=edu
>   cn: admins

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are interested in connecting to a ReadOnly LDAP or a read write.

However please make sure the configs are correctly done, and you've followed the steps in the document

[1]https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Configuring+a+Read-only+LDAP+User+Store - for Read Only LDAP user store

[2]  https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Configuring+a+Read-write+LDAP+User+Store- for Read/Write LDAP user store

If you have followed these steps correctly, the please post the configuration of your user-mgt.xml with the full configuration of the user store, mention which user store in which mode you would want to connect, and please also copy the server error message you get from the wso2carbon.log file you find at repository/logs or the server console.

Regards,
Shani

Comment: I am trying to set up ReadOnlyLDAP.  Your guides you linked show that   <Property name="ConnectionName">uid=AdminLDAP,ou=system</Property>  should be the same as <AdminUser>    <UserName>AdminLDAP</UserName>.  Is there no way to connect to ldap using a traditional admin account for ldap like 'cn=Directory Manager' but declare a different admin just for logging into the Identity Server?

Comment: If it's a read only LDAP, then you have to have a user who has  read all users/attributes and perform searches on the user store from your LDAP/Active Directory administrator  linked to WSo2 IS as a admin as well. The reason is that otherwise, wso2 IS will create the admin user if not existing. In a read only LDAP it would not be possible and hence would throw an error. If you do require different users, then you could create a different user in LDAP with the required privileges and link that user as the admin user in wso2 IS.

Comment: I added the full user store section and the startup error from the wso2carbon.log.   Using "cn=Directory Manager" as the Admin and as the connection name didn't work.  I know that cn=Directory Manager has full read/write power, however, it isn't associated with the role 'admins'.

Comment: The role name should not always be "admin".  The admin role you enter  should already exist in the read-only user store. Otherwise, you must enter an internal role, which will be saved to the internal database of the system when the system starts the first time. Please refer to the documentation https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Configuring+a+Read-only+LDAP+User+Store#ConfiguringaRead-onlyLDAPUserStore-RelatedTopics

Answer (score 0):

As per your ldapsearch command result, admin username as jwhitene would solve the startup error.

For example :

```
    <AdminUser>
        <UserName>jwhitene</UserName>
        <Password>xxxxxxxx</Password>
    </AdminUser>
```

---

Explanation :

If you are connecting to read only userstore, Admin user should be available in the userstore\ldap.

```
    <AdminUser>
        <UserName>cn=Directory Manager</UserName>
        <Password>xxxxxxxx</Password>
    </AdminUser>

    <Property name="UserSearchBase">ou=People,dc=pcc.edu,dc=cp</Property>
    <Property name="UserNameAttribute">uid</Property>
```

As per your ldap configurations quoted above, Identity server will looks for an user under `ou=People,dc=pcc.edu,dc=cp` directory which have property `uid` set as value `cn=Directory Manager`

Basically if there a such user, it would like this,

```
uid=cn\=Directory Manager,ou=People,dc=pcc.edu,dc=cp
```

Since you don't have such user, the server complains with that error log and set hold the start up flow.

The user that shown in the ldapsearch command result (uid=jwhitene,ou=People,dc=pcc,dc=edu) will match with above search pattern. Hence putting jwhitene as the admin user will resolve the issue

Comment: And sometime its need to check the config file's and logs to find out exact cause. If you don't get a direct answer, you can simply drop a mail to dev@wso2.org mentioning the problem and WSO2 community will help to sort out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

With help from techs at Ellucian, I just got my system working. 
Cause:I had an old version of OpenLDAP that used a different schema that did not match the defaults in the user-mgt.xml file.

Instead of `ObjectClass=groupofuniquenames` I configured my user-mgt.xml file using `ObjectClass=posixGroup` (which matches my OpenLDAP schema). I had to change the `ObjectClass` in a number of places. After that, my instance started up without any more problems.